# Set cookie from CodeIgniter and get the value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, cookies

I'm trying to get some data from a cookie. I set the cookie with CodeIgniter and here is my code

```
$c = array('name' => 'total', 'value' => $total, 'path' => '/');
$this->input->set_cookie($c);
```

Then, I want to take the data with javascript. This is what i've tried

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0; i<ARRcookies.length; i++) {
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name) {
      return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

console.log(getCookie('total'))
```

I got the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825700/9849804) but it doesn't work to my code. Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your javascript codes. Maybe it happens because the cookie is not yet set. You just have to add `expire` value to your cookie, set it to any number (in seconds) or `0` to set it to disable immediately.

```
$c = array('name' => 'total', 'value' => $total, 'path' => '/', 'expire' => 0);
$this->input->set_cookie($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the cookie you can use this

```
function readCookie(name) {
let nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=';
let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ')
        c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0)
        return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
}
return null;
```

}

`readCookie('total');`

This has worked for me multiple times, Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: There is no error, the function is working properly for other cookie